# Android device parameters which never change

Tags: android

In my project I have to generate a dynamic but deterministic string using device specific info/parameters which never change in the lifetime of the device, even after the Firmware or OS upgrade. E.g. Serial number, processor doesn't change, but what all other possible device info/parameters could be?

Comment: A custom ROM can return altered values for pretty much anything, including any "serial number".

Comment: If custom ROM is flashed then device is wiped and that is fine as per my requirement. I saw in the blog  that MAC address may not be available in all the devices when wifi or data is off. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)